# saving a date as dd/MM/yyyy in SQL database using NetBeans

Tags: java, swing

```
String d=(((JTextField)dobdatetext.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date fromDate = formatter.parse(d);  
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(fromDate.getTime());
```

I am trying to save sqlDate but in database it stores as yyyy/MM/dd format. Please somebody correct my mistakes so that i can get my desired results...

Comment: Why do you need to save it this way?  Let the system store it however it wants and format the data when displaying wherever.

Comment: Correction: the database stores a `Date` but its default display format will be `yyyy/MM/dd`.  But that shouldn't bother you at all, if you want to display the dates otherwise you should be able to do so by reconfiguring the db, see in the docs, it will be explained there.

Comment: Oh, if you are *going* to store text dates (although there are better DATE/DATETIME column types), [**at least use ISO 8601**](http://xkcd.com/1179/). Display in a locale-specific format is .. *display* and belongs at the client/app level. What happens if this program has to be used in a country where MM/dd/yyyy is commonplace? Yikes, talk about a data nightmare :(

Comment: I resides in India, here all application stores in this way, everyone else can do this, but truly no one of my friends and colleagues are helping me to short this out, so i repetitively come here for help.

Comment: @sudipta.dey Then all the (or at least those) applications are doing it wrong. *Help fix this!* The *display of data* should not affect the *storage of data*. The best method is to use a correct DATE/DATETIME column and *format it on the client when displayed*. Failing that (or in databases like SQLite without such types), use an accepted cultural-neutral format like ISO8601 and *format it on the client when displayed.* I format my dates different ways depending upon the client and use-case/context (and even by culture!), but the dates are *all stored the same* in the database!

Comment: @sudipta.dey Another reason why it is *really bad* to save dates like this is that they *cannot be easily ordered* and *cannot be ordered with an index* - range queries and order-by operations will not scale! Both DATE/DATETIME and ISO8601 approaches avoid this problem.

Comment: ok, thanks for your words, i got it now. Thanks a lot @user2246674

Comment: I come here to learn, and who are enjoying by giving downvotes, they are just wasting their time, i really don't care about reputation. I just love to learn, even from a student or a kid also. Thanks others who really tried to help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the database field is of type `date` (or whatever the vendor supports) and not text, then the format in the db is irrelevant.  Formatting is for output.

Answer (score 1):

in fact the format is used yyyy-MM-dd, just use a SimpleDateFormat to format the date value to the desired format when retriving a date value......

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String strDate = dateFormat.format(rs.getDate("column name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the to_date function :

```
insert into table_name(column_name)
                       values ( TO_DATE( d, 'yyyy/MM/dd' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of the date displayed in the default format configured in your SQL Server instance and doesn't depend on what date format you used in your application to set it.

Also, the format doesn't matter if you are storing date in a date column as you can retrieve the date in any format of your choice. See http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx on how to retrieve a data column in different date time formats. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing the dates in text, SimpleDateFormat has an applypattern method, so you can try

```
formatter.applypattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
sqlDate = formatter.format(/*date you want to format*/);
```